# javascript closure not working?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following code:

```
for (var i in listings){
  var listing = listings[i];
  map.addMarker({
    lat: listing.GeographicLocation.Latitude,
    lng: listing.GeographicLocation.Longitude,
    title: listing.Title,
    click: function(e){
      (function(listing){
         console.log(listing.Title);
      })(listing);
    },  
  });
}
```

when I click on the marker, I always get the title of the last listing.

Comment: Clear to me — questioner is asking the log message set via 'i' is not reflecting the value thought to be set by the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (var i in listings) {
  var listing = listings[i];
  map.addMarker({
    lat: listing.GeographicLocation.Latitude,
    lng: listing.GeographicLocation.Longitude,
    title: listing.Title,
    click: (function (listing) {
      return function(e) {
        console.log(listing.Title);
      };
    })(listing)
  });
}
```

You've placed the closure the wrong way round - it needs to be executed immediately, not when the click event is called.

Answer (score 2):

OK figured it out:

```
for (var i in listings){
  var listing = listings[i];
  map.addMarker({
    lat: listing.GeographicLocation.Latitude,
    lng: listing.GeographicLocation.Longitude,
    title: listing.Title,
    click: (function(listing){
      return function(e){
         console.log(listing.Title);
      })(listing),
  });
}
```